# Fixing compiled version

Tags: java, classloader

I had a look, and could not find any answers specific to my question, so I am making a new one.

So I am currently searching for a solution to an issue which is formally out of my control, but would be great if there was something I could attempt to do to fix it anyway.

The reason being is some of the classes being loaded are user provided and were not compiled correctly with the lowest compatible version of java, so it causes unpredictable java requirements.

Of course, this would only be done if necessary, but if it would have not loaded for that java version, attempt to patch the stamped java version so it would attempt it anyway.

Basically I am trying to correct(if possible) the stated compiled version stamped on java byte code, so that incompatible java version errors ideally are not thrown, even when they normally would, if the code could successfully be originally compiled on the lower java version in question.

Basically, other than the provided built in libraries which could be missing, I am not sure if the compilers have vastly different bytecode between different between versions. If this is the case, something like this could never work anyway.

Appreciate it, jdphenix, this is what I needed to know.

Sorry for whatever i did wrong here to get negative votes.

Comment: Could you paste the error or exception thrown by JVM? It will help to deduce the problem further.

Comment: @Mohan Raj Well, this is not actually my error, but an error I was brainstorming I could attempt to fix by injection, since the mods provided I have no direct control over, so this was more an exercise of what could or could not be corrected after compilation.

The errors I am talking about are the ones similar to 'Unsupported major.minor version 51.0'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the bytecode is in fact too different. The version stamped on the class is essential and would not work correctly if this is not correct. It could not be fixed this way, sadly, so you will at the mercy of others in this regard.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Java class files are forward compatible only. Therefore class files targeting newer versions that a system's JVM would not be able to be run.

There are breaking changes between major releases. Ones I can think of at a mental glance are varargs and generics in Java 5, for example.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I needed to know. Was my question offensive, or is the site full of trolling downvoters?

Comment: I don't believe your question to be off-topic for Stack Overflow. However, I am just the opinion of one here. The best insight I may be able to provide is a link to the help center article, http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic - you could also search the meta page at http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ to see if there's anything there.

Answer (score 0):

During classloading phase, JVM do bytecode verification. In the class file it will have information on which java version it was compiled  this helps the JVM to find out what is the current java version which tries to load and execute further. Class files are backward compatible you can compile on java 5 and can run in higher version where vice versa could not be done because of above stated verification.  Byte code can be injected on the already existing class file but if its not injected properly then  application may suffer some abnormal executions.

Comment: How JVM find the  java version compiled from class file?